When does the wing anti-ice valves open after take-off on the A320?
I know that if wing anti-ice is used on ground on the A320 the wing anti-ice valves will open for a period of 30seconds for a self test and then close as long as aircraft is on ground.
So my question is if wing anti-ice is kept ON when will the anti-ice valves open?
After lift off or in some other flight phase?

Well the heat has to be on for takeoff, so at minimum, it's going to be when thrust rises above some threshold with the system turned on.

The wing anti-ice valves are controlled by the state of the push-button, a timer and the ground/flight sensor:

Source: A320 FCOM, Ice and rain protection section.

If the panel push-button is switched ON on the ground, the valves open and are closed after 30s by a timer.

When in flight, the valves are open as long as the panel push-button is ON.


If the push-button is set to ON on the ground and left in this state, the 30s test is conducted, the valves close and only reopen when the sensor indicates the aircraft has left the ground. The valves then remain open until the push-button is set of OFF.
The bleed monitoring computer (BMC) may override this logic if required.

So the system lets you take off with the LEs cold even if the system is selected on?

@JohnK Ice protection on the ground is provided by anti-icing fluids. WAI cannot be used on the ground due to potential for overheating and structural damage. Same situation with 777 and the E-Jets.

On the CRJ200 you must have the system on and the LEs hot for takeoff (and by hot, I mean they are heated to above 100C, as an "evaporative" WAI system) for a TO in icing. WAI on takeoffs have a performance allowance in the QRH. Slats provide a lot more leeway I suspect, because they make the wing way less sensitive to contam. The 200's hard LE can tolerate very little LE roughness.
